# Express checkout payment in windows phone 8.1 and navigate from paypal site to my application

Tags: paypal, windows-phone-8.1, express-checkout

I am developing a shopping mobile application in windows phone 8.1 . I  want to integrate paypal for payment . As i saw the paypal SDK is terminated from windows 8 and the available SDK's for mobile applications are only for ios and Android , i tried to integrate paypal using the express checkout API . I have integrated and have done the payment . Now my question is after the DoExpresscheckoutpayment API call i get a response back from the paypal and it is displayed on my screen . How can i get the response returned by paypal in my application to figure out if the transaction is success or failure ? after that i want to return back to my mobile application page  from this paypal payment web page back to my mobile application last page. How can i achieve if anyone have done please help me . Or please update me any other better payment gateways than paypal express checkout .

Comment: is there any solution ?